# devstack installation failing tempest test-requirements

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am getting below error during installation of openstack via devstack in VirtualBox + Ubuntu environment

```
2016-10-03 06:10:04.370 | Collecting hacking<0.12,>=0.11.0 (from -r /opt/stack/tempest/test-requirements.txt (line 4))
2016-10-03 06:11:00.780 |   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f11a8f0dcd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/hacking/
2016-10-03 06:11:57.325 |   Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f11a8f23110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/hacking/
2016-10-03 06:12:54.374 |   Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f11a8f23250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/hacking/
2016-10-03 06:13:52.429 |   Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f11a8f23390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/hacking/
2016-10-03 06:14:52.491 |   Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f11a8f234d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/hacking/
2016-10-03 06:15:48.545 |   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hacking<0.12,>=0.11.0 (from -r /opt/stack/tempest/test-requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: )
2016-10-03 06:15:48.545 | No matching distribution found for hacking<0.12,>=0.11.0 (from -r /opt/stack/tempest/test-requirements.txt (line 4))
2016-10-03 06:15:49.404 | +inc/python:pip_install:1                  exit_trap
2016-10-03 06:15:49.435 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  local r=1
2016-10-03 06:15:49.473 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs -p
2016-10-03 06:15:49.513 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs=
2016-10-03 06:15:49.555 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:491                  [[ -n '' ]]
2016-10-03 06:15:49.595 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  kill_spinner
2016-10-03 06:15:49.627 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:383               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2016-10-03 06:15:49.653 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2016-10-03 06:15:49.692 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  echo 'Error on exit'
2016-10-03 06:15:49.692 | Error on exit
2016-10-03 06:15:49.710 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  generate-subunit 1475238914 236435 fail
2016-10-03 06:15:50.332 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:502                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2016-10-03 06:15:50.343 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:505                  /home/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2016-10-03 06:15:55.057 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  exit 1
```

I want to understand

- what exactly is this error reporting?
- is this linked to my local.conf
  file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved when tried to install the stable version

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/mitaka
```

I was trying to install the master branch and hence th installation was failing continuosly

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent devstack change that clobbers network routing. You can recover by running the devstack/unstack.sh script.

This networking issue makes the pypi repository unreachable unless you happen to be on the correct subnet already. Adding the following line to your local.conf is expected to be a temporary fix for this issue:

SUBNETPOOL_PREFIX_V4=10.1.0.0/24